# Test failure due to locator is not as expected

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have 'skip_testcases_on_fail' set to true and whenever there is a test failure due to css locator being incorrect, the other test methods in that file are not executed and the browser window remains open.

Is there a way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it is to check for the element using this.element (or browser.element) before doing anything else with it, such as getting text or clicking.

```
var self = this;

self.element('css selector', 'some_selector', function (present) {
    if (present.status !== -1) {
        self.getText('some_selector', function (result) {
            if (result.status !== -1) {
                console.log('result: ' + result.value);
                self.click('some_selector');
            }
        });
    }else{
        // the selector was not found
    }
})
```